# Why the result if different when using mean to fit the general model?

Tags: anova

I am dealing with real stats regarding the "Growing better pinot noir". https://realstat.science.unimelb.edu.au/

I am asked to average the "Trunk diameter in 2003(cm)" and make analysis using different treatments to see if the treatments are collectively effective and compare with each other to see the difference.

So, I've fitted the original data and do the ANOVA test regarding the treatments and blocks.
[image]

The P-value of Treatment rejects the null hypothesis.

However, when I average the "Trunk diameter in 2003(cm)" in Minitab, I got the opposite result, which doesn't make a difference whether using treatment or not.

[image]

Does this mean that I shouldn't average the data? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd consider averaging data. What's a good argument for doing so?

Comment: Actually, it's homework. However, it requests to average the data, which doesn't make sense to me, either. Thank you @Glen_b

Comment: If the aim is to demonstrate some potential costs of doing so, it might be a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: Yeah, if so, then it make sense.